# siteMeshInterceptor except a page

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, interceptor

i use siteMeshInterceptor for my spring mvc project. Is there a way excluding a page from interception? I want to solve this in dispatcherServlet, not in interceptor code.

inceptor looks like this in dispatcherServlet;

```
<property name="interceptors">
<list>
    <ref local="myInterceptor"/>
</list>
</property>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define different sitemash decorators for different url patterns.

`decorators.xml`

```
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/sitemesh/decorators">
    <excludes>
        <pattern>/login.html*</pattern>        
    </excludes>

    <decorator name="main" page="main.jsp">
          <pattern>/*</pattern>
    </decorator>    
    <decorator name="main" page="main.jsp">
          <pattern>/help/*</pattern>
    </decorator>        
</decorators>
```